# Make Image a DropDown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, navbar

Does anyone know how I can use an image as a nav bar,

I want to use my logo as a button so that when users click on the logo, a drop down menu appears that fills the entire page.

Currently I have a burger Tab and am implementing the drop down menu like so

```
          <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-field">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar"> 
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar right">
              <li class="active"><a href="Health.html">Health</a></li>
              <li><a href="Insurance.html">Insurance</a></li>
              <li><a href="Track.html">Track</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
     </nav>


 .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        background-color: darkgray;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 1% 0;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        border:0;
        background-image: i
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        float: right;
        min-height: 55px;
        padding: 0 15px 5px;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active 
     a:focus,  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a:hover  {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: darkgray;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li a {
        Color:#D5D5D5;
   }
```

Comment: drop down menus by their very nature do not take up a whole page :/ also, it would help if you slapped together a codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: I only want it to the fill the page on mobile devices, or is there a better way to approach this ? I mainly just want my logo to be the drop down menu

Comment: i'm struggling to understand exactly what you mean by a dropdown menu?!  [this](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_dropdowns.asp) is what i consider a drop down menu. notice how it doesn't occupy the entire screen. if u want a full screen menu to be "triggered" by clicking on your logo, the best bet would be to use javascript and just create a full page element with `display: none` initially, and listen for a `click` event on the logo which toggles the value of its `display` property

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5nttn4b6/

Comment: So to clarify I want my logo in the top right corner, and the user to click on that and the available option will drop down for the user to select, so yes it is a dropdown menu. and right that makes sense, ill look into doing it with javascript

Comment: you cannot listen for button "clicks" without javascript. i mean, if you don't know javascript or don't want to use it, instead you could use the `:hover` psuedo class to expose your menu if logo is hovered. otherwise, `document.getElementById('id-of-your-logo').onclick = function(){ if ([menu is not displayed do this]) document.getElementById('id-of-your-menu').style.display = 'block' else { document.getElementById('id-of-your-menu').style.display = 'none' }`

Comment: The bootstrap code you have up there can do what you want.

Comment: I don't mind using javascript, I am comfortable using it. How would you recommend I approach this

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you're fine with using JavaScript.

Add the following code to your HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="thePathToYourJSfile.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With CSS, style your menu however you wish to, but also add:

```
display: none;
```

And your JavaScript could look something like the following:

```
var logo = document.getElementById('id-of-your-logo')
var menu = document.getElementById('id-of-your-menu')

// this attaches a listener for the click event to your logo element
logo.onclick = function() {

  // when your logo is clicked, the code in this function will execute

  // the code below checks whether or not the menu is already displaying, and then displays the menu or hides it accordingly
  menu.style.display = window.getComputedStyle(menu).display !== "none" ? "none" : "block" 

}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks Anthony, So simply link the javascript in to the page and use css to add the logo and style it!

Comment: yes, in your HTML you must reference or link the JavaScript file. also, you can use CSS to style your logo and your menu however you want, but to give it the effect whereby your menu will only appear when you click the logo, you must first also hide the menu using CSS (unless you want the menu to be displayed initially)

Comment: Great, so just to clarify I add the logo in the CSS? and right so Ill have to make sure to set it to hide when the page first loads.

Comment: you can add your logo normally, using HTML, and style it normally, using CSS. yes, if you do not want your menu to be displayed when the page initially loads, you would want to hide the logo using `display: none;` in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks so much Anthony ill make sure to give it a go!

Comment: @harry let me know if u have any issues. im about to watch a movie, so if u do have issues youll prolly hear back from me in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

Your html had some small errors. It should have been like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-field">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
     </div>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar"> 
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar right">
          <li class="active"><a href="Health.html">Health</a></li>
          <li><a href="Insurance.html">Insurance</a></li>
          <li><a href="Track.html">Track</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </div>      
</nav>
```

If you encounter any trouble just tell us

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I Just added the corrected code you gave me (thank you by the way :P ) and im still getting a burger tab with text displaying (logo) next to it, is it possible to have just the logo display on all screens and then only when a user has clicked on it will it display the drop down menu?

Comment: Just added my logo to it , but it still displays outside of the burger tab, do I have to remove the span classes for the icon bar and replace that with the image I want to use?

Comment: It works(without your css). I've just tested. The logo area is another matter. You have two choices: 1) either to put just text or 2) image. But you have to create the image to fit in there. I usually use something called IrfanView to create such images.

Comment: can I make the burger tab area bigger to accommodate a larger logo ? or does it have to be small like the burger tab?

Comment: I also dont want the content of the menu to be displayed at all, just the logo , so when clicked the text appears is that at all possbile?

Comment: You can create a logo and use boostrap vissibliity class to display it only for desktop. Then for mobile just text can do or a separate image for mobile if you wish. Concerning menu, there is something called usability: visitors are used to clicking those horizontal menu symbol on the right. It confuses them if your menu has to display by clicking the logo. Normally a link to the home page on the logo is perfect

Comment: If you don't want the content of the menu to display on desktop, just use the visibility class to display it only for mobiles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162000/discussion-between-hanslutter-f-and-harry).